# Cypress screenshotOnRunFailure not working

Tags: automation, cypress, screenshot

According to Cypress documentation, Screenshots are automatic upon run failure.
This doesn't seem to be happening, however screenshots are recording in my file when I use `cy.screenshot()` directly in a test. I do not want to have to add this to every test.

My screenshot path is `\cypress\screenshots`
I am using `npm run cypress` to open Cypress and under "configuration" I have `screenshotOnRunFailure:true`

Any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you have in package.json under

"scripts": {
"cypress": "?"
},

"npm run cypress" (which runs your script called "cypress" from "scripts" section in package.json) is different from "cypress run" (which runs Cypress tests. By default works for creating screenshots when tests fail, with no need of writing lines: "screenshotOnRunFailure" and "screenshotsFolder" in cypress.json ).

Comment: Hi Tomasz
I have the below
`"scripts": {
    "test": "test",
    "cypress-{{environment}}": "cypress open {{environment}}--config baseUrl"xx",
    "cypress-{{environment2}}": "cypress open {{environment2}}--config baseUrl"xx",
}`

I did this so that I could run `npm run cypress={{environment}}` and the baseUrl would connect seamlessly to run all my tests in different environments.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I did also add the below and the config is true when loaded in cy
` "screenshots": {
    "screenshotOnRunFailure": "true"
  },`

Comment: "screenshotOnRunFailure" is used for "cypress run" (headless tests execution), while you use "cypress open" for headed execution. If you want use this key, please run tests by "cypress run".

Comment: Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Cypress will automatically capture screenshots when a failure happens during cypress run. Screenshots on failure are not automatically taken during cypress open. And be mindful of this too. Cypress clears any existing screenshots before cypress run. If you do not want to clear your screenshots folder before a run, you can set trashAssetsBeforeRuns to false.                                                                               
 Refer: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug with cypress.config.js. Configuring the screenshot defaults in commands.js works.

```js
Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
  screenshotOnRunFailure: false,
})
```